# Sitecore Schedule Publish Not Working

Tags: scheduled-tasks

We have the requirement like some items need to be published on specific time automatically.All Items are in two versions English and Japanese.

I downloaded the sitecore schedule publish package from market place.
[SITECORE SCHEDULED PUBLISH](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx#)

I installed  this on a Sitecore 8.2 update 3 instance without any error. I set a publishing schedule on a single item. But getting error "no valid version",please see below screen:

[image]

is there any settings need to do?

Comment: what version of sitecore are you using ? 8.3 doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, Sitecore 8.2 update 3 we are using

Comment: do the versions you are trying to publish have any publishing restrictions?

Comment: No, we did't restrict any item.

Comment: Does the item has a version in both `en` and `ja-JP`? This error will tend to be shown if the language you specified does not have at least 1 version.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in the `ScheduledPublish.dll`, the reasons why you have this error is because

1. One or more of your selected languages do not have at least a version.
2. The item is either in **Draft** or **Awaiting Approval** workflow.

The code make use of the `Sitecore.Data.Items.GetValidVersion` to see if the item has a valid version. It checks the date, if the item has been approved and allow empty items.

[image]